# node.js connect-redis redis.get(key,callback) return null

Tags: javascript, node.js

in connect-redis  to return session value use .get(sid, callback) 
 but it always return null so I think its not save in redis but I check it session save in redis correctly after investigation find problem is with Sid see  /connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js

```
  RedisStore.prototype.get = function(sid, fn){
   sid =this.prefix + sid;
    debug('GET "%s"', sid);

    console.log('lib');
    console.log(sid);

    this.client.get( sid , function(err, data){

      if (err) return fn(err);
      if (!data) return fn(null,'');
      var result;
      data = data.toString();
      debug('GOT %s', data);
      try {
        result = JSON.parse(data); 
      } catch (err) {
        return fn(err);
      }

      return fn(null, result);
    });
  };
```

if I but sessionID as string it will return session

```
  RedisStore.prototype.get = function(sid, fn){

  //  sid =this.prefix + sid;
    debug('GET "%s"', sid);

    console.log('lib');
    console.log(sid);

    this.client.get( 'lweUw//EdbygbGr/2gAZt0kb' , function(err, data){

      if (err) return fn(err);
      if (!data) return fn(null,'');
      var result;
      data = data.toString();
      debug('GOT %s', data);
      try {
        result = JSON.parse(data); 
      } catch (err) {
        return fn(err);
      }

      return fn(null, result);
    });
  };
```

Note:

typeof(sid) is string  even if  add qoute to sid  like this "\'sid\'"  it will return null

Comment: It would be helpful to see your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

The callback takes the form `callback(err, data)`. If there is no error, the first parameter will always be `null`. The real response is in the second parameter.

See: `return fn(null, result);` in `.get()`.

Comment: no data return the response it return from if condition see (!data) return fn(null,'');

Comment: You said it returned `null` in your question. An empty string is not `null`. Is the type of the return value a string?